# Find all empty repositories in Github

Tags: git, github

How to find empty repositories in Github under a certain account, we have a large number of git repositories and would like to know if there is an empty repo without any branches

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if the repository has no branches -

Method : `GET`

Endpoint : `https://api.github.com/repos/{repoOwner}/{repoName}/branches`

this returns an array of branch details .e.g:

```json
  {
    "name": "main",
    "commit": {
    "commit": {
      "sha": "....",
      "URL": "..."
    },
    "protected": false
  },
  {
    "name": "v-2.0.0",
    "commit": {
      "sha": "....",
      "URL": "..."
    },
    "protected": false
  }
]
```

If there are no branches then it returns an empty array - `[]`

Additionally, you can get the repository list using

Method: `GET`

Endpoint : `https://api.github.com/users/{username}/repos`

Official Docs by GitHub - [Read Here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#branches)